# How to make an element inside a col on Boostrap wider than the col?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for my english, I have a little question about Bootstrap.

I'm trying to make a website responsive and I have a row with 4 columns like this :

The div "seeMore" is hidden by default and, on click on the boxToggle element, it display block with a slideToggle. This works perfectly.

My problem is that I want that the div "seeMore" fits to the row which is 100% (like a col-lg-12).

I tried to put the div "seeMore" outside of the col-lg-3 and make a col-lg-12, it works ok on large screen but it's broken on tablet and phone because the div is not under his ancestor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boxToggle").click(function() {
    $(".seeMore").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);

body {
  font: arial sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  background: pink;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-body {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
}

.seeMore {
  display: none;
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

  <div class="box box-int box-options">

    <div class="box-header">
      <h2>Title here</h2>
    </div>
                 
    <div class="box-body" id="boxToggle">
      <div class="layout no-padding">
        <p>Some text here</p>              
      </div>
    </div>
                  
  </div>

  <div class="seeMore">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Some title here</h2> 
      <p>Blablabla</p>
    </div>        
  </div>

</div>

  </div>
```

I made a codePen too if you want to see : http://codepen.io/puzzleland/pen/BKrVJe

Thanks :)

Comment: Your row only has one column with 4 definitions on it.

in your pen, col-lg-3 is overriding all the other defs.  You need multiple column divs.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve. If you want the `.seeMore` div to fit the entire row width you can move the column class declaration from the outer div to the inner divs like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="row">

    <div> <!-- Delete the class from here and put the declaration inside .box and .seeMore -->

      <div class="box box-int box-options col-lg-3 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

        <div class="box-header">
          <h2>Title here</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="box-body" id="boxToggle">
          <div class="layout no-padding">
            <p>Some text here</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="seeMore col-xs-12">
        <div class="txt">
          <h2>Some title here</h2>
          <p>Blablabla</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is better then my (now deleted) answer.  One change I'd make however is I would replace `seeMore col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` with just `seeMore col-xs-12`.  If the smallest size is set to 12 and all other sizes need to be 12, the extra declarations are redundant.

Comment: @JosephMarikle thank you for the suggestion Joseph, you are right. I'm editing my answer according to that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already try this method, but it doesn't work on small devices because I want that the div "seeMore" go just under the div "box". If I do like you say, the div "seeMore" on small devices appears under another element. 

You can try to add more columns on codePen to see the result. I will do the same :)

Thanks again

Comment: @Puzzleland Yes, please update the codepen.  I'm not sure either of us understand what you are trying to achieve.